# "PIN Number" — why do we say it?

Tags: acronyms, redundancy

We often say "PIN Number", this is part of everyday conversation. But why?

PIN stands for Personal Identification Number, so what we're actually saying is Personal Identification Number Number.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Related: [Terms for duplicated words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7037/terms-for-duplicated-words)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid repeating word contained in an acronym?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14867/how-to-avoid-repeating-word-contained-in-an-acronym)

Comment: @FX_: Just wanted to point out that I discussed this with Kosmonaut in chat ([direct link to the conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/604952#604952)) and we agreed that this is not really a dupe.

Comment: Have you ever typed your PIN Number into the ATM Machine at an AIB Bank?

Comment: @RegDwight: Rightly or wrongly, I think it's a dup of Tragicomic's link. Colin's answer should have been over there in the first place.

Comment: Related to, but not quite the same, as "The La Brea Tar Pits".

Comment: Along with the mechanic looking for the VIN number on my car, and the electrician doing a PAT test on my equipment... PIN code is only just about acceptable, but I'm amazed at how many bank employees still use PIN number.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a special case of the [etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy). "PIN", like almost all words in every language, has its own meaning which is divorced from its etymology (in this case, its origin as an acronym).

In fact it has two related meanings, because it is still used as a stand-alone noun, closer to its origin ("I've forgotten my PIN"), as well as in its derived sense as a modifier ("PIN number").

One of the reasons for the prevalence of the derived sense is possibly the homophony of the ordinary word "pin". It's not that it's likely to be confused with the other meaning; it's that without context it may be unclear what you are talking about, so "PIN number" serves to narrow it down and give context.

Comment: The homophony with "pin" may not have that much influence, though, as the contexts are clearly separate (just as when somebody says "does your card have a chip", you know they're not referring to French fries, corn snacks or casino currency).

Comment: @Neil Coffey: Agreed.  Homophony doesn't help explain "ATM machine" (where you use your PIN number!) or "HIV virus".

Comment: @Neil: OK, maybe I went too far with that. Edited to reduce the weight of the point.

Comment: @Neil Coffey: if someone approached you saying "I lost my pin", the statement is truly ambiguous.

Comment: @Lie -- ish. Do strangers frequently approach you in a context that has nothing to do with either to inform you that they have lost either their pin or their PIN?

Comment: PIN and PIN number have exactly the same meaning so where is the fallacy?

Comment: @z7sg: the fallacy is in the argument that _because_ PIN is derived from the phrase "Personal Identification Number" _therefore_ "PIN number" is redundant. In current English you can make an argument that "PIN number" is redundant for the reason you give (and I also mentioned); but to argue that it is redundant _because of its origin_ (as the question does) is a fallacy.

Answer (score 13):

The so-called [RAS syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome) is quite common. Other examples are "LCD displays" and "ATM machines." Technically, it is a form of **tautology**. It happens because people are not aware of what the acronym stands for, so they just use it like any other word.

Comment: Yes, it is a tautology, but because "PIN" can be used on its own with the same meaning, not because the "N" originally stood for "number". See my reply re the etymological fallacy.

Comment: RAS Syndrome on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome

Comment: Often people are perfectly aware of what the acronym stands for, the sentence is just easier to understand that way.