# Is the proper phrasing "SMS" or "SMS Message"?

Tags: abbreviations, technical

I know that "SMS" stands for "Short Messaging Service." But,

> The term SMS is used as a synonym for all types of short text messaging as
>   well as the user activity itself in many parts of the world

(Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS)). Therefore, should I used the phrase "SMS" or "SMS Message"? This doesn't seem to be as straightforward as the obviously wrong (yet widely used) "ATM Machine" and "PIN Number."

Comment: Technically, "SM" would be the most proper way. But this acronym is already reserved :)

Answer (score 7):

First, there's nothing wrong with "ATM machine", "PIN number", or "scuba gear". The argument that they are redundant or erroneous is an example of the [etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy), the argument that how a word originated tells us the "right" way to use it today. Acronyms are *words* and they develop meanings that are not necessarily identical to the meaning of the words from which they are formed.

You can use either "SMS" or "SMS message". The term "SMS" can refer to either the service itself or a message sent using that service.

Comment: I disagree: while we still insist on writing ATM in all caps, it isn't a word; thus its expansion *is* relevant to proper usage, and the most charitable interpretation of "ATM machine" is that you suffer from a stutter.

Comment: @Martha: I vehemently disagree.

Comment: Is ATM an acronym or merely an abbreviation? Anyway, redundan or not, I don't see a problem with things like ATM machine either, it helps make your meaning clearer.

Comment: "ATM" can be loosely referred to as an abbreviation, but it is not technically one. To be super-technical, it is an initialism. It is unusual for an initialism not to be perfectly replaceable by the words it was formed from, so "ATM" is an unusual word, but not unique. Like "HIV", it has enough of an "adjective-y" feel to native speakers that it is frequently followed by the word its last letter stands for to make it feel more like a noun.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely agree (60%) with the etymological fallacy argument, but an upvote for a nevertheless good point.  @Marthaª You say ATM isn't a word, but ask any teenager off the street what ATM stands for.  Language evolves, and so do its rules! For the record, though, I'd never say "ATM machine".

Comment: About 1% of the time, "ATM" is followed by "machine". The same is true with "HIV" and "virus". Personally, "HIV virus" bothers me but "ATM machine" seems fine. But obviously different people have different views. My point is simply that the argument that "ATM machine" is wrong because the "M" stands for "machine" is a pure etymological fallacy. It could not be possibly be correct because language doesn't work that way.

Comment: [“PIN Number” — why do we say it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/pin-number-why-do-we-say-it)

Comment: @RegDwight: The first half of that answer is exactly how I would have answered that question. "PIN", however, is an acronym (since we pronounce it "pin", not "pee-eye-en"). But the point is the same; the current meaning and proper use of a word cannot be figured out by looking at the word's origin. Language doesn't work that way.

Comment: ATM is an abbreviation.  It has not taken on any new meaning beyond *automated teller machine*, regardless of whether the user knows what the letters stand for, so there is no possibility of an *etymological fallacy*.  The argument that redundancy is incorrect is an entirely different one.

Comment: Informally, initialisms and acronyms can be considered abbreviations.

Comment: Are you going to address the fact that the wiki page you linked on etymological fallacies only talks about *meaning* and not *usage*?  Perhaps you think wiki entry is wrong?  In that case why link to it?

Comment: I honestly don't think the distinction between meaning and usage is related to the question directly enough to be worth going into detail about. But the distinction is not really a bright line. This is basically just a rarer and more obvious form of the same fallacy -- if etymology doesn't even tell us correct meaning, it has no hope of informing usage.

Comment: The point is that in wiki a completely different thing is described, where meaning of a word has changed over time.  Here, there has been no change in meaning as ATM is simply an abbreviation (incidentally, the OED lists it as such despite your claim that this is informal - perhaps an etymological fallacy of your own?) Usage shows that ATM alone is preferred, especially in a formal context.  This is quite different from *scuba* which has become a word in its own right.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *SMS* in place of *SMS message* if you wish.

Here's an example taken from Orange:

> The first time you use this service you will receive an SMS with an invite to enter your twitter username and password.

[Here's](http://o2guru.tv/25b2) an "O2 guru" explaining "how to send an SMS".

In the UK, US and Australia most people call SMS messages *text messages* or *texts*, and sending SMS messages is called *texting*.

Comment: "In the UK most people call SMS messages text messages or texts, and sending SMS messages is called texting." 

Same in the U.S.  I'm in California, but I believe the same holds true elsewhere in the States.

Comment: Same in Australia. "SMS" was more common in the 90s, back when mobile phone use was less widespread.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer.  I thought it worth mentioning this difference in terminology with many parts of the world (Europe, Middle East, etc.) where they usually would use SMS.

Answer (score 4):

Use *["SMS message"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22SMS+message%22)*; everyone does.  I googled *["SMS" message](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22SMS%22+message)* and SMS alone always refers to the messaging service, not to an individual message.

I don't think it is as redundant as *PIN number* or *ATM machine*, since a *Short Messaging Service* message is a message using that service, whereas *PIN number*, for instance, *is* redundant.

Comment: +1 "SMS alone always refers to the messaging service, not to an individual message."  The idea of sending an entire service by text is rather absurd, so I quite concur.

Comment: Most people I've heard (in South Africa at least) purely use "I'll SMS you". It's common use - at least here.

Comment: @Rae: I don't think it does. If you google "send an SMS" (with the quotes), you'll see many uses of "SMS" to mean "a message sent using SMS".

Comment: @David Well, hence the question as to the correct usage...so perhaps it should be rephrased, "When used properly, SMS alone always refers to the messaging service."  Of course, I'm only basing correct usage on the meaning of the letters in the acronym.

Comment: But the question is not what the letters in the acronym mean.

Comment: Neither is the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it is completely wrong to say "SMS" is always the service. Merriam Webster defines "SMS" as "a technology for sending short text messages between mobile phones...also : a message sent using this technology : TEXT MESSAGE". If you're going to make a wide-reaching claim at least try to find a source. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/SMS