# Questions about abbreviations

Tags: phrases, abbreviations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“PIN Number” — why do we say it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/pin-number-why-do-we-say-it)

Assume we abbreviate *"Orthogonal Multi-user Channel"* as OMC. Is it correct to use the phrase *"OMC channel"* since *channel* is already contained in OMC?

Comment: But **OMC** is already an abbreviation for the [osteomeatal complex](http://www.mesothelioma-asbestosis.info/Lung-Diseases/sinus-infection). So as people who know about these things will be perfectly well aware, there's no redundancy in saying *"[the] four paranasal sinuses are interconnected through the osteomeatal complex (OMC) channel."*.

Comment: The language legislature has not yet ruled it incorrect.  Perhaps you should send them a petition.

Comment: @GEdgar: How can I do the petition?

Comment: It should go to [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as *RAS Syndrome*, or *Redundant Acronym Syndrome Syndrome*. Other examples of this are ATM Machine (Automated Teller Machine Machine) and PIN Number (Personal Identification Number Number).

This is not technically correct, but it happens pretty often.

Comment: Don't forget TLA (Three-Letter Acronym), and ETLA (Extended Three-Letter Acronym, used for acronyms with four letters).

Comment: @Jim: +1; spot on.  Every now and then, I run across someone who gets really irked by redundancies such as "VIN Number" and "CAC Card." It seems to happen rather naturally, however, and I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: According to which technical specification is it "not technically correct"?