# Is it correct to say "PC computer"?

Tags: acronyms

In Hebrew, it is common to say  "מחשב PC". The word "מחשב" means "computer", of any kind, and PC, well, a PC - personal computer.

While translating a technical document today I saw this being used, and was about to  translate it to "PC computer", when I realized it actually reads as "Personal computer computer", so I stopped.

Problem is, if I translate it to just "PC" or just "Computer", it doesn't feel correct to me, as not fully sticking to the original meaning in the document. Of course my feeling might be wrong, as far as English is concerned, and that is why I'm asking here.

So, can I say "PC computer", or is it plain wrong?

Comment: It is not idiomatic. You should use either "PC" or "personal computer." However, *personal computer* is often taken to mean a Microsoft Windows machine of some sort, so you may feel that it is better just to use "computer", providing that the context is clear.

Comment: Thanks @Mick, why not as answer? (And in this case it's indeed Microsoft Windows computer, if it matters.)

Comment: I like to provide supporting evidence when I post an answer. However, this is just from memory.

Comment: @Mick I see. Well, take your time, and thanks again! :)

Comment: It is impossible for us to say what is idiomatic in Hebrew.  As to the translation, it's a question of what your standard is -- idiomatic English or accurate (if awkward) translation.  "PC computer" is certainly heard in English, and while it may make some wince it's not a major faux pas.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks, "it's not a major faux pas" is kind of what I was hoping to hear. Think your comment is worth an answer, or do you also prefer to back it up with supporting evidence like Mick above?

Comment: Some prescriptivists say "PC computer" is bad.  But people keep on saying it.  Just like PIN number and many more.  If you want to say it, go ahead!

Comment: The one that makes me cringe is "JITC compiler".

Comment: Related: *[“PIN Number” — why do we say it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14868)*

Answer (score 2):

You should either use "PC" or "personal computer". You can replace "computer" with "PC" to speak about a particular kind of computer:

- Desktop PC
- Pocket PC
- Laptop PC
- Home Theater PC

Answer (score 1):

As @Mick commented, if you write PC computer, it could be (wrongly) interpreted as excluding Macintosh made by Apple. In order to include all the computers, you can write

> All PCs / PC and Mac computers.

According to the following Wikipedia article,

> "PC" is sometimes used in a different sense, referring to a personal
> computer with an Intel x86-compatible processor...
>
> "PC" is used in contrast with
> "Mac", an Apple Macintosh computer.
>
> This sense of the word is used in the Get a Mac advertisement campaign that ran between 2006 and 2009, as well as its rival, I'm a PC campaign, that appeared in 2008. Since Apple's transition to Intel processors starting 2005, all Macintosh computers are now PCs.

[Source: [Wikipedia article on Personal computer / Terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_computer)]

Comment: Thanks. Suppose it's clear in the context that only PC with Windows is to be used, does it mean I can use "PC computer"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why don't you use just PCs (personal computers) with Windows? It reads far more clear than PC computer and may not be misleading.

Comment: Well, the context is a software that works only on Windows, this is clear from other parts of the document. So adding "with Windows" is not needed in this case.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see. I think the other answer answers your question.

Comment: Windows Computer can't be abbreviated as WC, since that already means something else.