# What is it called when we follow an acronym with a word already in the acronym?

Tags: acronyms, redundancy, repetition

Example:

PIN Number (PIN=Personal Identification Number), no need to repeat number

RSVP please (RSVP=Answer please in French), no need to say please again

etc.

Comment: Or my pet peeve:  JITC compiler.

Comment: Answered at ["PIN Number" — why do we say it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/pin-number-why-do-we-say-it) (the special type of redundancy known as RAS Syndrome: Paul Rein's answer).

Comment: @Tonepoet - Shouldn't the note read "Possible RAS (Redundant Answer Syndrome) syndrome"?

Answer (score 4):

It's been given the ironic and self-referential label ***RAS syndrome***, where *RAS* stands for ***Redundant Acronym Syndrome***¹.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome):

> #### RAS syndrome
>
> RAS syndrome (where "RAS" stands for "redundant acronym syndrome", making the phrase "RAS syndrome" humorously self-referential) refers to the use of one or more of the words that make up an acronym or other initialism in conjunction with the abbreviated form, thus in effect repeating one or more words.
>
> Two common examples are "PIN (or VIN) number" (the "N" in PIN and VIN stands for "number") and "ATM machine" (the "M" in ATM stands for "machine"). The term RAS syndrome was coined in 2001 by New Scientist.

The more general term in linguistics is the unsurprising ***[redundancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics))***.

---

¹ <sub>Thus *RAS syndrome*, spelled out, is *redundant acronym syndrome syndrome*, just as *PIN number* spelled out is *personal identification number number*.</sub>

Comment: Does ELU really need two answers giving 'RAS Syndrome'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I answered before anyone suggested it was a dupe. You can feel free to close the question as a dupe. I won't mind.